# Algorithmically expanding a box to fill a space

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I have an array of box objects, defined by their (x,y,width,height) properties like so:

[image]
Box Q is anchored at corner point C. How can I programatically expand box Q to take up all the available space it has, while maintaining its aspect ratio?

I have had some luck by expanding box to be very large (from the top right corner) and then aligning to the top edge of the furthest box (in this case 5). If at that point other boxes overlap with Q, I remove the furthest box (5) and repeat (align to the top edge of 4), until no boxes overlap. The problem with this approach is that a box may overlap with Q (box 2 in the next image), but when I scale to meet its top edge, it is no longer contained, like this:

[image]

Any thoughts on an approach would be much appreciated,

Josh

Comment: "If they do, I remove them" --- what is "them"? You don't mean to remove box 2 in your example?

Comment: Edited to clarify, thank you.

Comment: You should scale to meet the right edge in addition to the top edge, and check which one actually meet, and choose the smaller one. In your example, if you scale Q by extending its bottom edge to align with 2's top edge, the rectangles do not meet. If you scaled Q by extending its left edge to meet 2's right edge, they would meet, so this is the actual limit.  If both meet, choose the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when I scale to meet its top edge, it is no longer contained

Instead scale to meet its

1. top edge
2. bottom edge
3. left edge
4. right edge

Then, see which scaling is valid (the box is contained after scaling) and results in the biggest box.

Comment: This may not be the most efficient way, but it is an approach that worked, thank you ciamej.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two approaches here.

First is to iterate over all other boxes. For each box `B`, see how much (by what factor) you can expand your given box `Q` so that it will touch box `B`; after that take the minimal of all such factors. However, finding this factor for a given `B` is a non-trivial task, though definitely solvable.

At the same time, if you already have a code that checks for overlaps for a given factor, then you can apply binary search to find the maximal factor that does not lead to overlap.

So you know that if you expand it a lot (say by `x` times), it does overlap. If you do not expand it (that is, expand by `1` times), it does not overlap. So you have a segment `[1,x]` where to search for an answer. Try the middle --- expand by `(x+1)/2` times and see whether it overlaps. If it overlaps, continue with segment `[1, (x+1)/2]`, otherwise with segment `[(x+1)/2, x]`. Take the middle of the new segment, and so on until the end values of your segment are close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that will take in a scaling factor as a parameter, and have it return true or false depending on if there is overlap found or not. It seems like you already have something like this function written.

Then use bisection search https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method to find your scaling factor to a threshold that is satisfactory.